# jQuery functions unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery

I have just started to learn jQuery and I faced with strange behavior of this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggle( "explode" );
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="head" >
    <div id="flag2" class="flag" ><img src="img/flag2.png"/></div>
    <div id="nickwrapper">
        <p id="nick">Text</p>
        <p id="undernick">Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="flag" class="flag" ><img src="img/flag.png"/></div>
</div>
```

instead of exploding image just disappears by becoming smaller....
but when I change  $("img") on class $(".flag") which is assigned for my images, picture change behavior.. it moves right and appear on the other level .. not like when it was $("img"). 
Why is it so?
I just want images of specific class to explode..

Comment: Can you show us the HTML as well? Also, a jsFiddle.net example is usually helpful in questions like this.

Comment: what does the jquery look like when you replace img with flag class?

Comment: what is the css for the explode class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class ".flag" is assigned to the wrapping DIV and not the img itself. So essentially with img you are exploding image. And with .flag you are exploding the DIV around it. You can put the class flag to the img tag itself.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you've got more of a problem with the css than with your JQuery selectors.

I would try something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("img").hover(function() {
            console.log("Hovered over image");
        });

        setTimeout(function(){
            $(someImageID).toggle("explode");
        }, 1000);
    });
```

This code will print to the console log whenever you hover over an image, and then separately will explode a single image after waiting 1000ms.

This will help you a) confirm that you're getting your selectors right, and b) make sure that the explode is working the way you want.  After you know both of those things are working, then you can combine them.

EDIT: I just saw that you updated the post to include your HTML.  The other answer is correct about the issues you're having with classes.

Answer (score 0):

You're using toggle, you should be using toggleClass

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/